# can't open a file in switch statement in c++

Tags: c++

I have a switch statement in my code, if the user chooses 1, he will be asked to write the file to write to,if he chooses 2; he will be asked to write the name of file to read from, but I get this error:

initialization of 'file_name' skipped by case label.

here is my code:

```
char FileName[100];
    char f[100];

    int choice;
    bool x;
    int idd,iddd;
    string line;
    cout<<"enter file name: "<<endl;
    cin>>FileName;
    ofstream products_out(FileName,ios::out);

    products_out<<table.p<<" "<<table.n<<" "<<table.a<<" "<<table.b<<endl;
    while(1){

    cout<<"1-add product"<<endl;
    cout<<"2-retreive product"<<endl;
    cout<<"3-update name"<<endl;
    cout<<"5-update cost"<<endl;
    cout<<"6-update quantity"<<endl;

    cout<<"4-exit"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        cout<<"enter id"<<endl;
        cin>>id;
        s.ID=id;
        cout<<"enter name"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        strcpy(s.name,name);
        cout<<"enter cost"<<endl;
        cin>>cost;
        s.cost=cost;
        cout<<"enter quantity"<<endl;
        cin>>quantity;
        s.quantity=quantity;
        x=table.insert(s);

        products_out<<s.ID<<" "<<s.name<<" "<<s.cost<<" "<<s.quantity<<endl;
        cout<<"yes inserted"<<endl;
            break;

    case 2:
        cout<<"enter id of product"<<endl;
        cin>>idd;
        cout<<"enter the file you want to open"<<endl;
        cin>>f;
            ifstream products_in(f,ios::in);
            products_in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            getline(products_in, line);
            if (line.find(id))
    {
        cout << endl << line;
    }


        break;
```

Comment: No the problem is that you cannot declare a new variable inside a switch statement

Comment: Interestingly enough, you show us different code. Firstly, there is no `file_name` in your code to which you refer in your warning message you allegedly see. Secondly, `FileName` is not used in the switch. Who are you trying to fool? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your case in braces like this:

```
case 2:
{
    cout<<"enter id of product"<<endl;
    cin>>idd;
    cout<<"enter the file you want to open"<<endl;
    cin>>f;
    ifstream products_in(f,ios::in);
    products_in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    getline(products_in, line);
    if (line.find(id))
    {
        cout << endl << line;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you start adding that much code into a case I would consider putting it into a function instead for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Switch cases are only labels, so them don't define scopes by themselves, and you cannot declare variables inside them. You have to put braces to make a scope inside the switch tag:

```
case 0: 
{
    std::ofstream os("myfile"); //Ok, note the braces
}
```

Of course because cases are only labels, you are not limited to write case-only scopes. You could play tricky games like this:

```
case 0: 
{
    std::ofstream ok_file("myfile"); //Ok, note the braces
case 1:
...
case 10:
}
default:
{
    std::ofstream error_file("other file");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code for each case into its own function. That will make the `switch` easier to read as well as removing this sort of complication.